# Длинный запрос или много коротких?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Всем добрый день, есть потребность взять данные с БД. +- 1000 условий (перечень айди). Лучше делать это отдельно или одним запросом через or?

Comment: Лучше через IN(1, 2, 3, и т.д.)

Comment: @Эдуард Спасибо) попробую

Comment: При 1000 значений WHERE IN будет не лучшим решением. Я бы создал временную таблицу ENGINE=Memory, вставил туда набор требуемых значений, проиндексировал, и использовал её в запросе. Это должно быть быстрее, чем запрос с "пухлым" список в WHERE IN - и уж тем более быстрее тысячи отдельных запросов.

Comment: а эти 1000 id условий вы откуда берете? не из другого запроса случаем? а то мб все можно inner join-ом решить

Answer (score 1):

Определенно нужно применить индексацию. И посмотреть на оптимизацию запросов (EXPLAIN).

Answer (score 0):

После выполнения этой задачи, я голосую за много коротких запросов и временную таблицу 
[Ускорить MERGE ORACLE / Оптимизация MERGE ORACLE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1072057/%d0%a3%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-merge-oracle-%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-merge-oracle)